Managing parameters for output files of simulation/data analysis
What is the best way to associate the employed parameters with the obtained tabular output file when performing computationally expensive data analysis or simulation?
I would like to keep track over the parameters I used (employed) in my scripts which take long to generate tabular (csv) output.
This should be a common problem, but I couldn't find a convenient (simple) solution to it.
In the back of my head, I remember having read an article about a software addressing this problem, but I forgot it's name.

If you have access or control over the model’s software, the easiest solution is to have it echo its inputs alongside the results.

Yes, but what would then be the best way to store the parameters alongside the generated output files so I could come back a year later and tell which parameters were used to generate a certain output file? The value of one parameter could easily included in the filename, but this results in long filenames with more parameters.

It’s pretty much impossible to answer you without knowing more about what you’re doing and how you plan to use it. I’d recommend against embedding data in the file names though, too easy to mess up and it requires parsing them in addition to parsing the output results. Note that any rigorous analysis of your data will likely route you through some statistics package(s), and they expect a tabular layout where rows correspond to experimental trials and columns contain input values and their corresponding outcomes.
